# Is this a white noise? Can I use ARCH/GARCH models on this?

Tags: correlation, garch, acf-pacf, white-noise

[image]

I am trying to find out if I can use ARCH/GARCH models. To my knowledge, to use ARCH/GARCH models you should have autocorrelation and this correlogram should not be a white noise. How can I know if this is a white noise or not?

Answer (score 0):

> To my knowledge, to use ARCH/GARCH models you should have autocorrelation

This applies to a *squared* time series, not raw, but this is actually what you have in your graph, so that is OK. It is a bit difficult to see, but some autocorrelations and partial autocorrelations at early lags (lag 1, perhaps also lag 2) appear to be statistically significant, though their sizes are not large. Thus, there are (weak) ARCH/GARCH patterns, and the time series is not white noise (though not necessarily very far from it).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check the presence of volatility clustering (arch effect).

Fit a simple regression of your returns versus s constant. Then from the menu bar in the box displaying the results of your analysis, view -> Residuals test -> Arch lm test.

If the test is significant, it detects the presence of volatility clustering and an Arch and you can use an Arch type model.